# UITextView doesn't disappear when removedFromSuperview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have two `UITextView`s, `self.instructions` and `self.textView`, that are supposed to alternate depending on what the user selects.

I create a `self.textView` like so:

```
-(void)createSpaceToWrite
{
  [self.instructions removeFromSuperview];
  [self.bar removeFromSuperview];
  [self createNavigationBar:@"Compose" selector:@"displayScreen" withDone:NO];  //This adds a UINavigationBar to the view.

  if (!self.textView)
  {
    self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 280, 150)];
  }

  self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14];
  self.textView.text = @"";
  [self.view addSubview:self.textView];
  self.textView.delegate = self;
}
```

Then I create `self.instructions` like so:

```
-(void)haikuInstructions
{
  [self.textView removeFromSuperview];
  [self.bar removeFromSuperview];
  [self createNavigationBar:@"Compose" selector:@"displayScreen" withDone:NO];

  if (!self.instructions)
  {
    self.instructions = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 125, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 10, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
  }

  self.instructions.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  self.instructions.text = @"Text of instructions";
  self.instructions.editable=NO;
  [self.view addSubview:self.instructions];
  [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```

The user starts with `self.instructions` displayed against the background image.  Fine.

The user switches.  The instruction text disappears, to be replaced by the editable `self.textView`, a white box.  Fine.

The user switches back.  The instruction text appears--but the white box is still there, even thought I've removed it from the superview.  And not only that, it's still editable and still brings up the keyboard when the user goes to edit it!

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Well, I basically scrapped all the code and started the class over from scratch, trying to be cleaner about everything, and I'm no longer having this problem, so it must have been something in some other method that was affecting it.  Lesson:  haphazard coding is bad!

Comment: `self.textView=nil;` try this line after this `[self.textView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it didn't change anything.  :(

Comment: ive tested your code seems it works as it should although i commented the `createNavigationBar:selector:withDone:`and added some buttons to call these two methods. did you properly adapt the <UITextViewDelegate> on the header file of the UIViewController, also did you declare this property as strong e.g. `@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextView *textView` and `@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextView *instructions`

Comment: Both properties are declared as strong.  I've included <UITextViewDelegate>, but I don't know what it means to "adapt" it.  Would you mind explaining?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to remove your text views interchangeably? Wouldn't it be better to just "hide" them interchangeably by setting the setHidden property like for example:

```
[self.textView setHidden: YES];
```

and additionally try the following also:

```
[self.textView resignFirstResponder];
[self.textView setEditable: NO];
[self.textView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];  
[self.textView setAlpha: 0.0];
```

Comment: Hmm....  Well, this does change things; the white box still stays there, but it's now in front of the instructions rather than behind them.  Still not what I'm aiming for, but at least it affects things....

Comment: Hm, strange! try also [self.textView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]]; and/or [self.textView setAlpha: 0.0];